# how to convert blob data into byte array and get image from DB and send it to UI through rest api

Tags: spring, rest, maven, spring-boot, cassandra

```
    @Override
    public byte[] findByusernameAndtenantId(String username,int tenantId) throws SQLException {


         Connection con=null;
         Blob img ;
          byte[] imgData = null ;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");


        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://169.46.155.77:9042/demo");


        String query = "SELECT PHOTO FROM  demo.IGNITE_USERS where USER_NAME=? and TENANT_ID=?";

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (result.next ())
        {   
          img = result.getBlob(1);
          imgData = img.getBytes(1,(int)img.length());

        }   
        result.close();
        stmt.close();

        }  catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            if (con != null)
            try{

                    con.close();
                } 
            catch (SQLException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                }
                con = null;
               }

           return imgData ; 
    }
```

this is my implementation code .

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/Image",method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="image/jpg")
      public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@RequestParam String username,@RequestParam int tenantId) throws  SQLException 
      {
        byte[] img=null;
        img=authService.findByusernameAndtenantId(username,tenantId);
        System.out.println("testing functionality");
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(img, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

this is my controller code

when I run the spring boot program , and do a POST call in Postman client to get the image I am getting Class not found exception : org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.Cassandra Driver.

Can you please help me  how to  return that image from cassandra DB stored as Blob ?

Comment: Add Cassandra Driver JAR to server classpath

Comment: already done that . Is there any other way to get the image without using cassandra driver in my code ? Can you please tell me how can I  use this piece of code  http://ac31004.blogspot.in/2014/03/saving-image-in-cassandra-blob-field.html and modify it to get the desired output in my code  as I am using  Spring boot with cassandra and getting the response as REST api.